# Initializing aggregate unions

Tags: c++, constants, unions

I've got a union :

```
union my_union 
{ short int Int16; float Float; };
```

I'd like to create :

```
const my_union u1 = ???;
const my_union u2 = ???;
```

and initialize their values to be of different types respectively :
u1 -> int16
u2 -> float

How do I do that ? If the above is not possible, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

union can have any number of constructors - this will work for any datatypes without constructor, so your example is well if exclude string (or make pointer to string)

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
union my_union 
{ 
    my_union(short i16):
        Int16(i16){}
    my_union(float f):
        Float(f){}
    my_union(const string *s):
        str(s){}

    short int Int16; float Float; const string *str;
};

int main()
{
    const my_union u1 = (short)5;
    const my_union u2 = (float)7.;
    static const string refstr= "asdf";
    const my_union u3 = &refstr;
}
```

There is more complicated way to create class, that owns by union, class must have a selector (scalar or vector datatype used) - to correctly destroy string.

Comment: Please do not use HTML tags to format your code - simply select the code with the mouse and type Ctrl-K.

Comment: DRY (don't repeat yourself). "5" is already int and "7." is alredy float. You don't need those nasty C casts.

Comment: then try to distinguish const my_union u1 = 0

This causes unambiguity between pointer const string * and short.
That is why for clearness only I've used explicit modifiers.

Answer (score 5):

Notwithstanding the ban on non-POD member data (as elaborated above) the Standard says:

at 8.5.1.15: When a union is initialized with a brace-enclosed
initializer, the braces shall only contain an initializer for
the first member of the union.

so

```
const my_union u1 = {1};
```

should work but this form cannot be used for the second (and subsequent) members.

Comment: So you have to pick how you want to initialize it and make that the first member.

Answer (score 2):

Unions cannot contain non-POD data types such as string, so your question is meaningless.

Comment: OP modified, question still stands

Comment: little correct: union can have any datatypes, that has not constructor or destructor.

Comment: also non-trivial assignment operator